# Computing dot products of linear combinations of unit vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

> For any unit vectors $v$ and $w$, find the dot products (actual numbers) of:
>
> a) $v$ and $-v$
> b) $v+w$ and $v-w$
> c) $v-2w$ and $v+2w$

I have worked part a :
a) $(v) \cdot (-v) = \cos (180) = -1$

Not getting any ideas on how to work part b and c... Any help ?

Comment: It is given that they are unit vectors, no specific values are mentioned though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that dot products distribute over addition and dot products are commutative and scalars can be pulled out from either vector. For any scalar $c$, we have that:
\begin{align*}
(\vec v + c \vec w) \cdot (\vec v - c \vec w)
&= \vec v \cdot \vec v - c(\vec v \cdot \vec w) +  c(\vec v \cdot \vec w) - c^2(\vec w \cdot \vec w) \\
&= |\vec v|^2 - c^2|\vec w|^2 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: really nice, so b and c evaluate to $1-c^2$ thank you so much :) one stone two birds ! xD

Answer (score 4):

Dot product abide by distributive and commutative law. Feel free to distribute and commute.

b) $$ (v+w).(v-w) = v.v + v.(-w) + w.v + w.(-w) = 1 - v.w + v.w -1 = 0 $$
c) $$ (v-2w).(v+2w) = -3 \; \; \; (similarly) $$

Answer (score 2):

How about using the linearity of dot product? For the first component, we have $(a+b,c)=(a,c)+(b,c)$. Similarly for the second component.

Comment: could you please kindly elaborate a bit more

Comment: thank you :) should it be okay to expand it using FOIL ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the distributive and commutative properties apply to dot products (as said in other answers), the difference of two squares identity holds for dot product.

b)

$$(\mathit{v}+\mathit{w}) \cdot (\mathit{v}-\mathit{w}) = \mathit{v} \cdot \mathit{v} - \mathit{w} \cdot \mathit{w}=1-1=0$$

c)

$$(\mathit{v}-2\mathit{w}) \cdot (\mathit{v}+2\mathit{w}) = \mathit{v} \cdot \mathit{v} - 2\mathit{w} \cdot 2\mathit{w} = \mathit{v} \cdot \mathit{v} - 4(\mathit{w} \cdot \mathit{w})=1-4=-3 $$

For clarity, $\mathit{v} \cdot \mathit{v} = 1$ because $\mathit{v}$ is a unit vector (same for $\mathit{w}$) and $(c_1\mathit{v}) \cdot (c_2\mathit{w}) = c_1c_2(\mathit{v} \cdot \mathit{w})$ because scalar multiplication applies to dot product.